# Dynamically loading jQuery fails only in some sites

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Code:

```
p_initJQuery();

function p_initJQuery() {
if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js")
    script_tag.onload = punctis_load_box;
    script_tag.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') punctis_load_box();
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script_tag);
} else {
     punctis_load_box();
}
}

function punctis_load_box() {
    $(".punctis-social-box").html(typeof jQuery);
}
```

---

Thats how im controlling the site does not have already loaded jquery because this code is meant to be inserted on pages that i don't know anything about, if not loaded, it loads it. This is working fine on my [test site](http://infoabout.me/punctis/punctis.php) but if i tried it on another more [complex one](http://www.delfinsblog.it/2013/01/06/bigdata-analysis-for-improve-the-hiring-process/), it fails with *Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function*

I have no clue whats going on.

Comment: Perhaps the page uses `jQuery.noConflict()`?

Comment: Dont know, I know the wordpress theme loads jquery, but my script have to be able to handle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code load jQuery when there's no jQuery defined before, but your site have jQuery already.

(I think it's included in your wordpress theme)

So you can use the `jQuery` object. If you can't use `$`, that's because jQuery is under 'no conflict mode'.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Just use `jQuery` instead of `$` or redefine `$` by `window.$ = jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: I don't recommend overwriting `$`

Comment: I changed to Jquery instead of $, there is no error but the div does not get updated on the complex site...

Comment: @JanDvorak yea maybe it can makes some real 'conflict'. but that's one of solutions haha